# Javascript DRY Design Patterns - Functions vs Object

Tags: javascript, function, object, design-patterns, dry

Below is a code snippet of a function that creates and appends div HTML objects.  The function is called from another function which appends additional elements to it.

I'm finding myself writing similar code as whats illustrated below. I know there has to be another more efficient way writing this code. What dry design pattern should I using?  Is the object notation better for something like this? Examples would be great.

```
function create_element_container(){
  var newElement = document.createElement('div'); //create container element
      newElement.className = 'dropped'; //add classes to container element      

  var controllerContainer = document.createElement('div');
      controllerContainer.className = 'drop-element-controls';

      newElement.appendChild(controllerContainer);//Append controller container to main div

  var controller_left = document.createElement('div');
      controller_left.className = 'drop-move-controller';

      controllerContainer.appendChild(controller_left);

      var controller_left_move = document.createElement('div');
          controller_left_move.className = 'drop-move';

            controller_left.appendChild(controller_left_move);

            var controller_left_icon = document.createElement('span');
                controller_left_icon.className = 'fa fa-question fa-lg';

                controller_left_move.appendChild(controller_left_icon);

      controllerContainer.appendChild(controller_left); //Append controller Left


  var controller_middle = document.createElement('div')
      controller_middle.className = 'drop-sortable-controller';

      controllerContainer.appendChild(controller_middle);

      var controller_middle_sortable = document.createElement('div');
          controller_middle_sortable.className = 'drop-sortable';

          controller_middle.appendChild(controller_middle_sortable);

            var controller_middle_icon = document.createElement('span');
                controller_middle_icon.className = 'fa fa-arrows fa-lg';

                controller_middle_sortable.appendChild(controller_middle_icon);

      controllerContainer.appendChild(controller_middle); //Append controller Left


  var controller_right = document.createElement('div')
      controller_right.className = 'drop-remove-controller';

      controllerContainer.appendChild(controller_right);

      var controller_right_move = document.createElement('div');
          controller_right_move.className = 'drop-remove';

          controller_right.appendChild(controller_right_move);

            var controller_right_icon = document.createElement('span');
                controller_right_icon.className = 'fa fa-remove fa-lg';

                controller_right_move.appendChild(controller_right_icon);

  return newElement;

}
```

Comment: stop writing so many `var`, There are people with OCD here

Comment: @vsync: There's nothing wrong with the `var`s. What *is* odd is the seemingly arbitrary indentation, and the double calls to `controllerContainer.appendChild(controller_*)`

Comment: yes there is wrong with them. there is more than one of them. also the indentation is obviously off.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for your comments. I didn't think there was anything wrong with the vars, isn't it good practice to declare a new variable with var. Also what do you mean the double calls to to controllerContainer these calls are sequential to append to the elements. The person below did list another style that took out the redundancies. @vsync how would you write the function/object?

Comment: see my answer, with the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would write a `createElement` function:

```
function createElement(tagName, className) {
    var element = document.createElement(tagName);
    element.className = className;
    return element;
}
```

Next I would rewrite your `create_element_container` function as follows:

```
function create_element_container() {
    var newElement = createElement("div", "dropped");

    var controllerContainer = newElement
        .appendChild(createElement("div", "drop-element-controls"));

    controllerContainer
        .appendChild(createElement("div", "drop-move-controller"))
        .appendChild(createElement("div", "drop-move"))
        .appendChild(createElement("span", "fa fa-question fa-lg"));

    controllerContainer
        .appendChild(createElement("div", "drop-sortable-controller"))
        .appendChild(createElement("div", "drop_sortable"))
        .appendChild(createElement("span", "fa fa-arrows fa-lg"));

    controllerContainer
        .appendChild(createElement("div", "drop-remove-controller"))
        .appendChild(createElement("div", "drop-remove"))
        .appendChild(createElement("div", "fa fa-remove fa-lg"));

    return newElement;
}
```

You can do this because `parent.appendChild(child)` returns the `child` element.

Answer (score 1):

Your code consists of this repeated:

```
var controllerContainer = document.createElement('div');
    controllerContainer.className = 'drop-element-controls';

    newElement.appendChild(controllerContainer);
```

You might want to consider [`put-selector`](https://github.com/kriszyp/put-selector). With `put`:

```
var controllerContainer = put(newElement, 'div.drop-element-controls');
```

Doing that cuts down that function by 2/3rd. Then even combine the calls:

```
put(controllerContainer, 'div.drop-move-controller div.drop-move span.fa.fa-question.fa-lg <<');
```

Replaces:

```
 var controller_left = document.createElement('div');
      controller_left.className = 'drop-move-controller';

      controllerContainer.appendChild(controller_left);

      var controller_left_move = document.createElement('div');
          controller_left_move.className = '';

            controller_left.appendChild(controller_left_move);

            var controller_left_icon = document.createElement('span');
                controller_left_icon.className = 'fa fa-question fa-lg';

                controller_left_move.appendChild(controller_left_icon);

      controllerContainer.appendChild(controller_left); //Append controller Left
```

That cuts it down by 15/16th.

Another option is to just create the first element:

```
var newElement = document.createElement('div'); //create container element
    newElement.className = 'dropped'; //add classes to container element
```

And then do:

```
newElement.innerHTML = '<div class="drop-move-controller"><div class="drop-move"><span class="fa fa-question fa-lg"></span></div></div>...';
```

Note that the HTML above only includes the `div` with the class `drop-move-controller`.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve another plug-in but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how many times it would run. if not many, then I would prepare a string of DOM and just use `innerHTML` to put everything in some container. this would be more readable and maintainable.

### Basic example:

```
function create_element_container(){
    var elm, template;
    
    elm = document.createElement('div'); //create container element
    elm.className = 'dropped';
    
    template = '<div class="something another"> \
                    <span></span> \
                </div> \
                <span class="foo"></span>';
    
    // this makes our template text into a real DOM elements
    elm.innerHTML = template;
    
    return elm;
}
```

Comment: Great approach, very clean! I think a combination of this and @Aadit code will work perfectly.

Comment: there is no combination :) his and mine are totally different things. you either use this or that, but there is nothing more simpler than my approach, unless you're using jQuery...and still, not by much at all.

Comment: Your code is missing the controller element container. Also my code  is a bit more involved I just posted a snippet of the function.

Comment: my code is only a sample, you can write anything you want as the "template"... thousands lines of HTML. it will be maintainable because it looks exactly like HTML..using actual templates is even better. see http://handlebarsjs.com/